# fetch complete element from xml file using lxml python library

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using below code to filter out one element completely (with all sub-elements) from xml file which I am parsing to ET. but in the output I receive nothing, could you help me to fetch my data:

Code :

```
from lxml import etree
parsedXML = etree.parse("data_xml.xml")
parsedXML=StringIO(parsedXML)
a=parsedXML.xpath('//measInfo[@measInfoId="67109488"]')
```

data_xml:

```
<measCollecFile>
 <measData>   
   <measInfo measInfoId="67109488">
                <granPeriod duration="PT3600S" endTime="2018-04-21T01:00:00+04:30"/>
                <repPeriod duration="PT3600S"/>
                <measTypes>67194363 67194364 67194365 67194368 67194369 67194370 67194371 67194372 67194373 67194374 67204393 67204394 67204395 67204396 67204764 67204765 73441531 73441532 </measTypes>
                <measValue measObjLdn="BLRNCH03/FEGE:PN=3, SN=25, SRN=1">
                    <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
                </measValue>
                <measValue measObjLdn="BLRNCH03/FEGE:PN=2, SN=25, SRN=1">
                    <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
                </measValue>
                <measValue measObjLdn="BLRNCH03/FEGE:PN=1, SN=25, SRN=1">
                    <measResults>0 0 0 0 61043.406 35116.8 45024.105 301966.509 165096 223853.859 20260847268 100734236526 154174172 191309061 0 0 53039.886 238680.333 </measResults>
                </measValue>
                <measValue measObjLdn="BLRNCH03/FEGE:PN=0, SN=25, SRN=1">
                    <measResults>0 0 0 0 71847.747 37518.4 50369.693 303467.379 164086.4 221952.38 22666361970 99878571071 162303835 193826669 0 0 64721.428 235521.769 </measResults>
                </measValue>
                <measValue measObjLdn="BLRNCH03/FEGE:PN=3, SN=24, SRN=1">
                    <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
    </measInfo>
 </measData>
</measCollecFile>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to output? Your code doesn't output anything (except maybe for an `AttributeError`).

Comment: The XML is not valid. `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: measValue line 19 and measInfo, line 21, column 20`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, actually I take our from 20MB xml file, sorry for that

Comment: @CristiFati, I expect to have mentioned element in a variable to work on Element, not whole xml data

Comment: Don't know what your comment means, but regarding the `AttributeError`, I was talking about this: `parsedXML.xpath...` where `parsedXML=StringIO...`.